# How to display the sales flash on a single product page using elementor?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

I use elementor to design the product pages in woocommerce and would like to know how to display the sales flash option using elementor. Currently I don’t see any option so can it be called as a shortcode?
I am able to show for archive products as the option is visible but for a single product no such option.

Comment: Check this plugin maybe?: https://woocommerce.com/products/sale-flash-pro/

Comment: Hey, was looking at an option without any plugin

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've been through this too. There is a way to show sale flash on singles products in Elementor but it's very tricky. The steps needed to show such a badge is as follows:

1. Edit a product archive page using Elementor using the top admin bar and the button "Edit with Elementor"
2. In this edit mode search for a widget called "Archive Sale Badge". Unfortunately this widget only appears for the archive pages.
3. Add the widget anywhere in a container and in the label field put in these magic words (I couldn't find any documentation on this):

   %percentage_sale% Special Offer
4. Do any styling that you prefer.
5. When you are finished, right click on the widget and click "Save as global". This way you can reuse this global widget anywhere.
6. After saving the global widget, exit the archive page edit mode without saving it.
7. Edit a desired page, like single product, with Elementor and add this custom widget from your templates library. If this doesn't show up in click the refresh button of the library.

Happy flash sale-ing!